# OCJPexam garabage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given:

```
public class GC {
    private Object o;
    private void doSomethingElse(Object obj) { o = obj; }
    public void doSomething() {
        Object o = new Object(); // line 5
        doSomethingElse(o);
        o = new Object(); // line 7
        doSomethingElse(null);
        o = null;
    }
}
```

When the doSomething method is called, after which line does the Object created in line 5
become available for garbage collection?

i think answer shuld be after line 7..bt the answer is after line 8..explain me where i am wrong..

Comment: Kindly remove the numbers and format your code.

Comment: This link will help you. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/22/how-do-objects-become-eligible-for-garbage-collection/

Answer (score 3):

An object can be garbage collected only when it becomes unreachable. In your code after line 7. you can still access(reach) the object created on line 5. through the `this.o` field.

After line 8. `this.o == null` and so the object created on line 5. becomes unreachable.

**Reachability Rules:**

- [Java Language Specification - 12.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.2)

Comment: Actually my doubt is- in method doSomething the local variable o is currently storing the address of the object it has created in line 5..now in line 7 the same reference variable which we have created in line 5 is now storing the address of the same object or it is storing the address of some newly created object in line 7? if it is not storing the address of that same object in line 5 than now no reference variable is having address of the object in line 5 and hence it is ready for garbage collection after line 7 itself? plz tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: @user2789395 You are correct that the local variable `o` is no longer storing the reference to the object after line 7. But the method `doSomethingElse` stores whatever you pass it in the field `o` (note this isn't the local variable `o`). So after line 7 the variable is still stored in `this.o` field.

Comment: @user2789395 Happy to have helped!

Comment: i am unable to post a que..what should i do? it is asking to format the que and i have done formatting but still  it issaying the same thing..plz help..how should i post that que..i need explanation of that que urgently..

Answer (score 2):

The Object o in line 5 is a local variable to the method `doSomething()`.

It will become orphaned after the execution of line 8.

As both the local and global references will no longer refer to the object.

**Edit:**

Though this is very late but I hope it might help someone someday.

You can receive such events this by using the using the library that i am developing called [gcRadar](https://github.com/R-daneel-olivaw/gcRadar). It provides events when an object is orphaned and after the actual garbage collection of the object.

Any suggestions for improvements in the library are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For an object, becoming available for GC does not ensures that object will be GC'ed right away. It really depends on implementation of the GC.

Since you are talking about Java, it also depends on the state of the program being run. The program can be interpreted or it can be JIT'ed.

If it is being interpreted, I think it would be available for GC at line 8, when you set it to null. If it is JIT'ed, it can (logically) be garbage collected at line 7, because the newly created object will not be used.